# Session in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, session, firebase, react-native

I am trying to store the logged in user as a session in react native. Here is the code where I check for the login credential:

```
login = () => {
    // code to retrieve from firebase
    query.once( 'value', data => {
        data.forEach(userSnapshot => {
          let userKey = userSnapshot.key;
          var accountData = userSnapshot.val();
          var password = accountData.password;

          if(passwordInput != password){
            console.log('invalid credential.');
          }else{
            console.log('successful logged in.');
            // store the userKey as session to be used in other pages
          }
        });
    });
  }
```

I managed to grab the unique push ID for user if successfully logged in. Any idea on how to store it as a session?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

You can use [AsyncStorage](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/asyncstorage.html) to store your data. Here is some example

**Persisting data**

```
try {
  await AsyncStorage.setItem('Key', 'I like to save it.');
} catch (error) {
  // Error saving data
}
```

**Fetching data:**

```
try {
  const value = await AsyncStorage.getItem('Key');
  if (value !== null){
    // We have data!!
    console.log(value);
  }
} catch (error) {
  // Error retrieving data
}
```

**Remove Data**

```
try {
  AsyncStorage.removeItem('Key');
} catch (error) {
  // Error retrieving data
}
```

**Clear All Data**

```
try {
 AsyncStorage.clear();
} catch (error) {
 // Error retrieving data
}
```

Comment: @JeffereyRajan But the error message told me that await is a reserved word.

Comment: if you want to use `await` functionality then you have to use `async ` before starting the function example: 
async function fetchJSONAsync(url) {
  let response = await fetch(url);
  let body = await response.json();
  return body;
}

Comment: So in my case, login = async() => {} ? if I don't put the await, the code can be compiled perfectly, just that when I tried to getItem(), it returns me [object Object]

Comment: yes like this. const login = asyn () => {
try {
  await AsyncStorage.setItem('Key', 'I like to save it.');
} catch (error) {
  // Error saving data
}
}

Comment: I see but how do I retrieve it? Because the getItem[] is currently returning me [object Object] rather than its value